# Import nested Python dict in Julia

Tags: python, julia

I have developed a Python script which loads data from excel files  (.xls/m, .csv etc) processes it (stores it in nested dictionary) and uses that data to solve a non convex optimization problem.

After discovering the amazing [NonConvex.jl](https://github.com/JuliaNonconvex/Nonconvex.jl) package, I would like to take advantage of the algorithms and obviously the speed up from Julia.

Since the data loading module is already written in Python, I would like to continue using that. For non convex optimization i would like Julia to work with the pre processed data (from Python script and in the form of nested Python dictionary).

Is there a recommended way to export the nested dictionary from Python and import into Julia.

Thanks!

I have used Pickle to export nested dictionaries from Python and import the pickle file in Julia using Pickle.jl, and didn’t succeed.

I have also tried exporting Python dictionary as a json object but failed as my nested dictionary contains Int64 data type and json.dump doesn’t work with it.

Comment: What does "didn't succeed" mean? If you want help with figuring out how to fix any of your attempts, you will have to show some code along with the outcomes. See [ask] for some tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through this procedure successfully:

1. Python:

   ```
   >>> dictionary = {
   ...     1:{"key1":[1, 2, 3]},
   ...     2:[3, 5]
   ... }

   >>> import pandas as pd
   >>> pd.to_pickle(dictionary, "thepickle.pickle")
   ```
2. Then, using the [`Pandas.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaPy/Pandas.jl) in Julia:

   ```
   julia> using Pandas: read_pickle

   julia> dictionary = read_pickle("thepickle.pickle")
   Dict{Any, Any} with 2 entries:
     2 => [3, 5]
     1 => Dict{Any, Any}("key1"=>[1, 2, 3])
   ```

Note that you can use either `pickle` or `pkl` as the file type suffix.

Comment: Thanks @Shayan! That really helped. I had to sort out the ENV[“PYTHON”], but after that it worked. I am getting some pyObjects in some of the Julia dict values, and I am working to sort it out.

Comment: @tuckdales, you're welcome. Ask a new question anytime if no one has asked about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can load pickle via `PyCall`.

I just managed to run the following code:

```
import numpy, pickle
d = { "A":[1,2,3], "B":np.array([4,5,6], dtype='int64') }
with open("c:\\temp\\file.bin","wb")  as f :
   pickle.dump(d,f)
```

Now I try to load in Julia via PyCall and works like a charm:

```
julia> using PyCall

julia> pickle = pyimport("pickle");

julia> open("c:\\temp\\file.bin") do f
       d = pickle.load(f)
       end
Dict{Any, Any} with 2 entries:
  "B" => [4, 5, 6]
  "A" => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks @Przemyslaw! 

I tried your solution and it worked for a smaller dictionary. But when I exported full dictionary it threw this error: TypeError(“a bytes-like object is required, not ‘str’”). Sorry I can’t share the code snippet or full error as I am working with sensitive data. I can try to recreate this using generic data and repost.